# NiFi - Merge data returned by paginated API

Tags: apache-nifi

I've a API which returns the 200 records at a time. If I've 600 records, I need to fire the API 3 times to get all the records with offset. Here is my design to get the paginated data:

[Configuration for getting paginated data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZHqn.png)

My question is, how to combine all 600 records into array and process further. (Note: In realtime I'll have around 100k records to process). I tried with MergeContent, but all the records are not combining. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try `MergeRecord` or `MergeContent` with higher thresholds for their "bins." They'll wait until they have enough data or a user-specified timeout occurs before sending the data they have downstream.

Comment: Thank you @Mike. But how do I set the threshold? Like sometimes data can be retuned in seconds, sometime it may take longer. Same with amount of data. So on what basis we can decide on this?

Comment: With the bin size and age fields.